# How Do I access a global variable from one keyword to another in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

```
Create_And_Apply_DRPolicy
    ${DRPolicyNameLongevity_Win}=  Create DR policy with frequency    &{drpolicy}
    Set Global Variable    ${testpolicy}    ${DRPolicyNameLongevity_Win}  
Pause_DRPolicy
    Click Element ${testpolicy}
```

Here, I am getting error as "Variable 'testpolicy' is used, but not defined"
Here, `Create_And_Apply_DRPolicy` is one keyword & `Pause_DRPolicy` is another keyword

Comment: The error is quite explicit - you are trying to use the variable `${testpolicy}` which isn't defined yet. Check your execution order, most probably you are calling `Pause_DRPolicy` before `Create_And_Apply_DRPolicy`.

Comment: No, actually the execution order is correct.
I have defined a global variable in  "Create_And_Apply_DRPolicy" keyword. So, ideally it is expected that it should be available everywhere in the scope.So it should be available to "Pause_DRPolicy" keyword as well.